# First or limit in Rails scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following scope:

```
scope :user_reviews, lambda { |user| where(:user_id => user) }
```

I apply this in the controller:

```
def show
  @review = @reviewable.reviews.user_reviews(current_user).first || Review.new
end
```

The `first` is to limit to search the current user's one and only review. Now I try to write a new scope `user_review` which I tried many ways to chain the `user_reviews` scope with `first`, but just couldn't get it what. Something like this:

```
scope :user_reviews, lambda { |user| where(:user_id => user) }
scope :user_review, lambda { |user| user_reviews(user).first }
```

I know the above `user_review` is wrong, but just trying to show you guys what I am trying to do.

How should I write this properly?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see a big problem with what you have. A scope that only returns one object isn't really a scope anymore. You can define methods inside a scope's block but that would be redundant in this case (e.g. a `def first` method that simply calls `.first` on the scope results).

Comment: @TomL, your idea works. Please put it as an answer, so that I can mark it and give you credit. Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just stick with your original idea:

```rb
scope :user_reviews, lambda { |user| where(:user_id => user) }
```

and call `user_reviews.first`. Nothing wrong with that.

Definitely do not define a scope that returns a single object. A scope should be chainable.

Comment: "_Definitely do not define a scope that returns a single object. A scope should be chainable._" I totally agree, and i would like to add that it sound like a conception mistake to use `scope` that way. I think it would be a better choice to use a `has_one/belongs_to` relation

Answer (score 1):

I also used this:

```
  def self.user_review(user)
    self.user_reviews(user).first
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

I feel this use case is very common.

We can solve this by following:

```
scope :user_reviews, lambda { | user_id | where(:user_id => user_id) }
```

and then in the model have `user_review` as class method

```
def self.user_review(user_id)
    user_reviews(user_id).first
end
```

Now you can call `user_review` and it'll return the one record.

Answer (score -2):

```
      scope :user_reviews, ->(user) { where(user_id: :user) }
```